# how can I select the first-child, when It is in a div

Tags: css, css-selectors

this is my code and I am going to select first child that is `<span>`

```
<div class="textTextmenu">
      <img src="pic/postimage.png"/>
        <span>
            I need to select this span
        </span>
        <span>
            span 2
       </span>
   </div>
```

*I want to do this with **first-child**, but I don't know how to use `first-child`*

Like this:

```
.textTextmenu span:first-child{
 /*
    writing code here
 */
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, your HTML says you need to select the `span` but your post and CSS say the image is not selected. Which one is it?

Comment: sorry I was wrong , now will make it true

Comment: `first-child` of **same type** is span and img is single element!

Comment: Ok, I un-deleted my answer

Comment: You've changed your code to be correct (invalidating the answers), so what is the problem?

Comment: I bet you can give that first span a class and that you are just overthinking this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is all to make you understand

```
1)    .textTextmenu span:first-of-type { color:red } 
2)    .textTextmenu :nth-child(1){border:1px solid red;}
3)    .textTextmenu span:nth-child(2){color:red;}
```

[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/WtqpP/)

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/WtqpP/2/)

[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/WtqpP/3/)

Comment: Thank you, That is true, is there any way to use first-child?

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `.textTextmenu span:first-child` will not match anything. The [`first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) of `.textTextmenu` is an `img`.

You might actually want to look into [`first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type), or [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child), e.g.

```
.textTextmenu span:first-of-type {}
```

or

```
.textTextmenu :nth-child(2) {}
```

Other approaches that would work in this particular example are [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) or [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child), like so:

```
.textTextmenu span {
    /* Style the first span */
}
.textTextmenu span + span {
    /* Style the next span */
}
```

or

```
.textTextmenu span {
    /* Style the first span */
}
.textTextmenu span:last-child {
    /* Style the next span */
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This answer is really complate

Answer (score 2):

## I'm kind of confused as to what you want but...

```
.textTextmenu img:first-child{
  border:2px solid red;
 /*How to select First child? / this way is wronge and image is not selected*/
}
```

right?

Comment: thank you, can you tell me how can i select first-child that is span with first-child .

Comment: @Kermani you cannot select the span with `first-child` as it is not the first child of its parent, the `<img>` is.  use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` if you want the span.  those are your only options. you already should know this from the question you asked 15 minutes ago...

Answer (score 2):

```
.textTextmenu img:first-child{
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

this will select first img tag inside the div

Comment: thank you, can you tell me how can i select first-child that is span with first-child

Answer (score 1):

Is this be good? It selects each span after image in textTextmenu

```
.textTextmenu    img + span {}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry didnt see the image before span

Comment: This is good if you need to support old browsers ie8 and lower. If you are supporting higher than you can use nth-child like in other answers

Answer (score 1):

any reason why you cant use `first-of-type`?

```
.textTextmenu span:first-of-type {
  ...styles go here... 

}
```

NOTE:  as with many CSS pseudo-selectors, `first-of-type` is just an alias for `nth-of-type(1)` just as `first-child` is an alias for `nth-child(1)`

Answer (score 1):

To select the image, instead of:

`.textTextmenu span:first-child{}`

do

`.textTextmenu img:first-child{}`

Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/763K9/

Answer (score 1):

```
.textTextmenu img + span{
  border:2px solid red;
 /*How to select First child? / this way is wronge and image is not selected*/
}
```

See the demo http://jsfiddle.net/nUwDb/